# AutocompleteTextView in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am new to Xamarin. I am trying to bind an object to AutocompleteTextView in Xamarin Android. I am able to attach the adapter but when I type in text in the AutoCompleteTextView the object is displayed as is and not the text. I added Event Handler for Item Click and able to get the value that i want to display. 
Below is my code and any help or pointers on how to get to display the value as suggestions.

Main Activity

public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        int count = 1;

```
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.myButton);

        //button.Text = 
        MainActivityModel Mv = new MainActivityModel();
        ArrayAdapter<AutoCompleteTextModel> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<AutoCompleteTextModel>  
            (this,Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleDropDownItem1Line,Mv.StationsList);

        AutoCompleteTextView actv = FindViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(Resource.Id.source);

        actv.Adapter = adapter;
        //actv.Threshold = 1;

        actv.ItemClick += (object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e) => {
            actv.Text = Mv.StationsList[e.Position].StationName;
        }; 

        actv.TextChanged += (object sender, Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs e) => {

            new ArrayAdapter (
                this, 
                Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, 
                Mv.StationsList.FindAll (a => a.StationName.Contains(actv.Text)).ToArray ());
        };


        button.Click += delegate {
            button.Text = string.Format ("{0} clicks!", count++);
        };
    }
}
```

AutoCompleteTextViewModel

public class AutoCompleteTextModel
    {
        public string StationName { get; set; }
        public int StationId { get; set; }

```
    public AutoCompleteTextModel ()
    {
    }
}
```

public class MainActivityModel
    {
        public List StationsList;

```
    public MainActivityModel ()
    {
        StationsList = new List<AutoCompleteTextModel> ();

        StationsList.Add (new AutoCompleteTextModel () {StationId = 1, StationName = "Chennai Beach"
        });
        StationsList.Add (new AutoCompleteTextModel () {StationId = 1, StationName = "Chennai Fort"
        });
        StationsList.Add (new AutoCompleteTextModel () {StationId = 1, StationName = "Chennai Park"
        });
        StationsList.Add (new AutoCompleteTextModel () {StationId = 1, StationName = "Chennai Egmore"
        });
        StationsList.Add (new AutoCompleteTextModel () {StationId = 1, StationName = "Chetpet"
        });
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

[image]

_objGeneralDetailProductType is the objecttype of AutoCompleteTextView

You can try this to bind the list in Auto Complete because in my hand, i am using it and it is working fine.

Comment: You should also define what type of data is in your list. Suppose, as above in question. Explain him how can you access "StationName" , if you are using above list in question.